# Oracle Custom Class Wizard fails to generate custom c# class from Oracle User Defined Datatype

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, odp.net, server-explorer

I am trying to generate custom .NET classes from an Oracle User-Defined Type from Visual Studio Server Explorer (Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio and Oracle Data Provider for .NET are installed).

I created a basic User Defined Type using server explorer as shown below:

[image: Creating a user defined type using server explorer]

After that I tried to generate custom class as shown below:

[image]

But when I am trying to complete the wizard:

[image]

in the the final step of the Wizard I am getting the following error:

> Oracle Custom Class Wizard
>
> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

[image]

I am not able to find why I am getting the error. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: What version Database are you running, and are you running the latest ODP.NET drivers? (12C r2? )  Did you look at the Event Log to see if anything was in there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify Oracle connection and use "Oracle Database (ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver)"

`Data source = "Oracle Database"`
`Data Provide = "ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver"`  (Default was ODP.NET, managed Driver)

using `"ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver"` data provider this error will resolve 
(Its works for me in VS2012)